# Selecting element with html tag and class on click function not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <dt class="odd">...</dt>
  <dd class="odd">...</dd>
  <dt class="even">...</dt>
  <dd class="even">...</dd>
  <dt class="odd">...</dt>
  <dd class="odd">...</dd>
  <dt class="even">...</dt>
  <dd class="even">...</dd>
</div>
```

the sturcture above have `dt` with class odd and `dt` with class even, what i want is when i clik the `dt` with class odd the next `dd` with class odd will show or hide, but the problem is my on click function for dd is not firing at all, here's the code:

```
$( "dt.odd" ).click(function() {
   alert('odd');
   $(this).parent().next('dd.odd').show();
});
```

Comment: Check console for errors.. Have you included jQuery ? Code looks fine and working for me..

Comment: no error at all, i already included the jquery, when i change the selector for click function to only `$('dt').click` without odd it firing the click function

Comment: Are you adding elements dynamically ?

Comment: @Rayon no, i'm using php loop to generate this html

Comment: what is the default status of the div, are they display none or block?

Comment: @GaneshPutta for the dd it display none, fot dt display block

Comment: @IdhamChoudry — Just add jQuery and make executable snippet in your question.. It should work...

Comment: @IdhamChoudry try my below code may be this will help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, may be this will help u

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
dt{
 display:block;
}
dd{
 display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "dt.odd" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <dt class="odd">...</dt>
  <dd class="odd">...</dd>
  <dt class="even">...</dt>
  <dd class="even">...</dd>
  <dt class="odd">...</dt>
  <dd class="odd">...</dd>
  <dt class="even">...</dt>
  <dd class="even">...</dd>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @GaneshPutra thanks, after wrapping it inside document ready function it works

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "dt.odd" ).click(function() {
   alert('odd');
   $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show and hide respective **dd** on click of **dt** then you can use below snippet :

```
$( "dt.odd" ).click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

When you click on **dt** it will show next **dd**, if not visible and vice-versa